# como limitar la lista de una datalist?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, datalist

tengo una datalist que me retorna todas las marcas de productos para hacer una busqueda, el problema es que el datalist se despliega en toda la pantalla, y quiero recortar la cantidad de registro que me entrega visulmente, el código es el siguiente:

```
                             <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                                <input class="form-control" name="marca" list="marca" autocomplete="off" name="marcas" id="xd" type="text" placeholder="Marca...">
                                <datalist id="marca">
                                    @foreach ($marcas as $item)
                                    <option value="{{ $item->ARMARCA }}">
                                    @endforeach
                                </datalist>
                            </div>
```

Comment: [No es posible modificar un datalist](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-datalist-element), por ej con CSS, ya que cada navegador le asigna un diseño diferente, si es que lo soporta, algunos agregan un overflow, otros solo ocupan todo el alto según su contenido.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes limitar la colección al numero que necesitas, por ejemplo si solo quieres mostrar 10.

```
<datalist id="marca">
 @foreach ($marcas->take(10) as $item)
  <option value="{{ $item->ARMARCA }}">
 @endforeach
</datalist>
```

Aunque lo mejor seria colocar el limite en el controlador

```
$marcas = Marcas::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
```

De esta forma siempre tendrás los 10 últimos

Comment: no me funciona ya que solo me toma 10 y no todos los de la tabla